# Не отображается картинка, как можно исправить?

Tags: html, css

Подключаю картинку из файла `index.php`:

```
<div class="images-item-">
      <img src="/../img-main/bond.png" alt="james bond">
</div>
```

Каталог файлов выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако картинка не появляется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
<img src="/../img-main/bond.png" alt="james bond">
```

примените

```
<img src="../img-main/bond.png" alt="james bond">
```

т.е. **без слеша** перед двумя точками, т.к. начальный слеш обозначает самую верхнюю папку.

Comment: К сожалению пробовал так, не помогло.

Comment: И где находится файл `index.php`? Я не вижу его на вашей картинке.

Comment: Забыл переименовать, исправил картинку.

Comment: В решении моей проблемы это не помогло, к несчастью.

Comment: Как не помогло?! Ваш код в таком виде, как вы его показали в вашем вопросе, **бы все равно не работал**, *вне зависимости от того, если бы вы переименовали или переименовали неправильное имя картинки.*

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте расширение файла картинки, у меня часто такая ошибка встречается
Например, у вас не jamesbond.png, a jamesbond.jpg. Также попробуйте открыть файл самостоятельно, он мог быть поврежден

Как вариант создайте схожую файловую структуру и поэкспериментируйте в ней. Но ответ участника MarianD абсолютно верен и логичен

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).